# jQuery get style of element with specific data attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using bxSlider and I created a custom pager by using the pagerCustom option. I want the pager to look like a thumbnail pager so I tried copying the style of each slide and appending it to each pager. Example: Pager 1 should have the style of slide 1, pager 2 for slide 2, and so on..

This is what I have right now as a pager:

```
<div class="custom-pager">
 <a data-slide-index="0" href="" class="">1</a>
 <a data-slide-index="1" href="" class="active">2</a>
 <a data-slide-index="2" href="" class="">3</a>
 <a data-slide-index="3" href="" class="">4</a>
</div>
```

and my jQuery code is this:

```
$('#slider .custom-pager a').each(function(){
 var test = $(this).parent().index();
 $(this).attr('style', $('*[data-slide=" ' + test + ' "]').attr('style'));
});
```

I added data slide to each bxSlider list:

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: auto; position: relative;">
    <li data-slide="0" style="background: transparent url(&quot;_assets_/images/slide-1.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; float: none; list-style: outside none none; position: absolute; width: 1903px; z-index: 0; display: none;"></li>
    <li data-slide="1" style="background: transparent url(&quot;_assets_/images/slide-2.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; float: none; list-style: outside none none; position: absolute; width: 1903px; z-index: 50; display: list-item;"></li>
    <li data-slide="2" style="background: transparent url(&quot;_assets_/images/slide-1.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; float: none; list-style: outside none none; position: absolute; width: 1903px; z-index: 0; display: none;"></li>
    <li data-slide="3" style="background: transparent url(&quot;_assets_/images/slide-2.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ; float: none; list-style: outside none none; position: absolute; width: 1903px; z-index: 0; display: none;"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you try `console.log(test);`?

Comment: Oh, the question is that it's not working. No style is being copied.

Comment: try getting the index as `var test = $(this).data('slide-index');`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$('*[data-slide=" ' + test + ' "]')
```

is wrong based on your html in two ways:

- your attribute is 'data-slide-index' not 'data-slide'.
- you have extra spaces which you don't need after equals (also you don't need to begin with *). The extra space means that the value should be e.g. ' 1 ' instead of '1'.

So your select is not selecting anything.
You can use:

```
$('[data-slide-index="' + test + '"]')
```

Also, consider if $().css() is useful to you. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: he is trying to copy style from data-slide to data-slide-index

Answer (score 0):

If you use the index passed to [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) you don't need to use `test`, also, as mentioned by @TigOldBitties you have some extra spaces on your selector. Try this

```
$('#slider .custom-pager a').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('style', $('[data-slide="' + index + '"]').attr('style'));
});
```

Comment: it's 'data-slide-index' or as phobia82 said .data('slide-index'), just 'data-slide' doesn't work.